# Javascript for loop does not wait for fetch request to complete and moves onto next iteration

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I have below code in javascript in which some asynchronous task is being performed:

```
async function fetchData(id){
 for(let i=1;;++i){
   res = await fetch(`https://some-api/v1/products/${id}/data?page=${i}`,{//headers here});
   res = await res.json();
   if(res.length==0) break;
   else{ //do some work here and continue for next iteration}
 }
}

async function callApi(){
 var arr = [//list of id's here to pass to api one by one, almost 100 id's here];
 await Promise.all(arr.map(async(e)=>{
    await fetchData(e);
 }));
}
callApi();
```

The above code looks fine to me, except that it doesn't work as expected. Ideally, what should happen is that unless one id's call is not completed( unless break condition not satisfies for one id), the for loop should not proceed to next iteration. Rather, I am getting totally different results. The api calls are happening in random order because the loop is not waiting the iteration to complete. My hard requirement is that unless one iteration is not complete, it should not move to next one.

`await` seems to have no effect here. Please guide me how can I achieve this. I am running out of ideas.

Thank You!

Comment: I don't think the `.json()` function would ever return undefined. It either throws an error or returns a parsed document. Did you mean to catch an error?

Comment: The api that I am using, sometimes returns a response which throws ``invalid json`` error on ``res.json( )``. Apart from checking for ``undefined``, I can also check if length of ``res`` is 0 because the api return an array of documents

Comment: You are not returning anything from your `fetchData`. I would expected you to accumulate the pages and then `return` them. Also you should use a `try` `catch` for the `fetch` part instead. I would expext fetch to throw when `page=${i}` query fails. Then `map` in `callApi` will run all `fetchData`'s in parallel. What exactly you need if you clarify i can perhaps show the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My actual requirement is that in one iteration, until the fetch operation is not complete, the loop should not move to the next iteration.

Comment: Also, is it true that map function runs parallely? If that is the case, I don't want it to execute like this. I want it to be serial, picking one id at a time and moving to the next one only when the execution of last one is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your `arr.map(...)` is not awaiting the different fetchData calls before the next map call, so I'd turn this into a specific for loop to be sure it waits:

```js
async function callApi(){
  const arr = [...];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    await fetchData(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

or alternatively use a for of

```js
async function callApi(){
  const arr = [...];
  for(let a of arr){
    await fetchData(a);
  }
}
```

The `fetchData` function also looks like it could use some improvements with error handling, but since you shortened your code quite a bit, I'm assuming there is something like that going on there, too, and your issue is actually with the callApi() code instead, as the fetch and await looks good to me there.

Comment: I have changed map into a for loop, but the same issue still persists. It is not awaiting for the fetch to be completed.

Comment: @NodeFriend that is weird, as both fetch() and response.json() are asynchronous functions that return a promise, and you're using a normal for loop so it should wait until the fetch function returned its value. I'm starting to suspect that waiting for the fetch to go through isn't the actual issue at hand here but that it's something else somewhere else. Are you sure it's handling errors properly? Are you sure it's not called in order (confirm with console logs or something)?

Answer (score 0):

You should decide either to use promises or async await. Don't mix them.

With promises you can always use funky abstractions but with a simple recursive approach you can do like

```
function fetchData(hds, id, page = 1, pages = []){
  return fetch(`https://some-api/v1/products/${id}/data?page=${page}`,hds)
         .then(r => r.ok ? r.json() : Promise.reject({status:r.status,pages})
         .then(j => fetchData(hds, id, ++page, pages.push(doSomethingWith(j))))
         .catch(e => (console.log(e.status), e.pages));
}
```

So we use recursion to fetch indefinitelly until the API says enough and `r.ok` is `false`.

At the `callApi` side you can use `reduce` since we have an `ids` array.

```
const ids = [/* ids array */],
      hds = { /* headers object */ };
function callApi(ids){
  return ids.reduce( (p,id) => p.then(_ => fetchData(hds,id))
                                .then(pages => process(pages))
                   , Promise.resolve(null)
                   )
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

So now both accesses to the `id` and `page` data are working asynchronously but only fired once the previous one finishes. Such as

```
(id=1,page=1) then (id=1,page=2) then (id=1,page=3) then (process 3 pages of id=1) then
(id=2,page=1) then (id=2,page=2) then (process 2 pages of id=2) etc...
```

While I love the promises, you can also implement the same functionality with the `asyc await` abstraction. I believe the idea behind the invention of the `async await` is to mimic sync imperative code. But keep in mind that it's an abstraction over an abstraction and I urge you to learn promises by heart before even attemting to use `async await`. The general rule is to never mix both in the same code.

Accordingly the above code could have been written as follows by using `async await`.

```
async function fetchData(hds, id){
  let page  = 1,
      pages = [],
      res;
  while(true){
    res = await fetch(`https://some-api/v1/products/${id}/data?page=${page++}`,hds);
    if (res.ok) pages.push(await res.json())
    else return pages;
  }
}
```

Then the `callApi` function can be implemented in a similar fashion

```
const ids = [/* ids array */],
      hds = { /* headers object */ };
async function callApi(ids){
  let pages;
  for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    try {
      pages = await fetchData(hds,ids[i]);
      await process(pages); // no need for await if the process function is sync
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I find promises quite difficult to understand and Implement. I often use ``async/await``.